# Any alternative to while loop in conditional scenarios in solidity?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, nft, gas-price

I am developing an NFT Marketplace with Dropsite module where free NFTs will be Distributed randomly. There are 3 categories of NFTs with fixed number as follows:
Platinum: 150,
Gold: 350,
Silver: 500

Now I want to build a logic in which if 150 from Platinum, or 350 from Gold or 500 from Silver category are minted, The random number should be generated again. This can be done easily using while loop but I want to avoid this as it would be too expensive in terms of gas fee.

How can I omit this?
I have the following logic for now:

```
function randomMint() contractIsNotPaused public returns (uint) {
    uint nftId = random();
while((Platinum<=150 && nftId==0) || (Gold<=350 && nftId==1) || (Silver<=500 && nftId==2))
    {
        nftId = random();
        if(nftId==0)
        {
            data="Platinum";
            Platinum++;
        }
        else if(nftId==1)
        {
            data="Gold";
            Gold++;
        }
        else if(nftId==2)
        {
            data="Silver";
            Silver++;
        }
    }
_mint(_msgSender(), nftId, numOfCopies, data);
TotalNFTsMinted++;
dropsite_NFT_Owner[_msgSender()]=nftId;
return nftId;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some comments, no need loops here, it will add a lot of computations and you're calling random() on each loop.

```
function randomMint() contractIsNotPaused public returns (uint) {
    // no need to call random() multiple times
    uint nftId = random(); // we're assuming that random() returns only 0,1,2
    // if nftID is 0, and less than 151 so 150 MAX
    if(nftId == 0 && platinum < 151) {
        data = "Platinum";
        Platinum++; 
    // if nftID is 0 or 1 and platinum is more than 150, it will go there
    } else if(nftId <= 1 && gold < 351) {
        data = "Gold";
        Gold++;
    // if any of the above conditions are filled it will mint silver if enough silver available
    } else if(nftId == 2 && silver < 501) {
        data="Silver";
        Silver++;
    } else {
        if(gold < 351) {
            data = "Gold";
            Gold++; 
        } else {
            data = "Platinum";
            Platinum++;
        }
    }
}
```

I'll recommend to avoid using `string` if possible

Comment: Thank You!
A minor change worked for me!